# Converting Latitude/Longitude/Altitude to XYZ coordinates in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinates, wgs84

I want to simulate real-time in Unity using GPS data (Latitude / Longitude/ Altitude) of the aircraft moving in another flight simulator. In this way, the aircraft in Unity, should act the same as the aircraft in the other simulator.

As is known, Unity uses the xyz coordinate system. I have studied many examples to transform these two different types of data into one another. But in all of them, problems occur in coordinate transformations and aircrafts move differently. However, I still do not understand how to do it. 
Is there an easy formula for realizing this transformation?

Here are a few examples of instant data I receive from the simulator:

```
<GPS>
    <Lat>21.325352</Lat>
    <Long>-157.929607</Long>
    <Al>885.512322</Al>
</GPS>
<GPS>
    <Lat>21.325356</Lat>
    <Long>-157.929555</Long>
    <Al>886.829367</Al>
</GPS>
<GPS>
    <Lat>21.325357</Lat>
    <Long>-157.929540</Long>
    <Al>887.487356</Al>
</GPS>
```